# Entity with id already exists and does not exist simultaneously in CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm banging my head against the wall on this one.

I've got a function that is basically an Upsert called `TryCreateOrUpdate`. I do realize that an upsert function now exists, but this is some older code. Here's the function:

```cs
public static async Task<string> TryCreateOrUpdate<T>(T data) where T : ViewModelBase
{
    var options = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data.PartitionKey) ? null : new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(data.PartitionKey) };
    try
    {
        var response = await Client.CreateDocumentAsync(Collection.SelfLink, data, options, true);
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException dce)
    {
        switch (dce.StatusCode.Value)
        {
            ...
            case HttpStatusCode.Conflict:
                try
                {
                    var link = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(_databaseId, _collectionId, data.Id);
                    await Client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(link, item, options);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return $"There was an error updating the document.";
                }
                break;
            default:
                ...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "There was an unknown error creating the document.";
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

I'm trying to insert a document with an id that is 6 digits as a string.

I checked my Cosmos DB and I can confirm that there is no document in the database with the id which I am trying to upsert. So it should result in a create.

The line that creates the document throws a `DocumentClientException`:

> Entity with the specified id already exists in the system.

However, the replace line of code throws this exception:

> Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.

Um, what? Does it exist or not?!

As I said, I check before I run this and the document doesn't exist.

I even tried changing all this code to use the newer `UpsertDocumentAsync` and I still get the error

> Entity with id already exists in the system

even though, as I've said, the document DOES NOT EXIST.

Comment: Is the caller of this method `await`ing the call? Is the entire stack of calls using `await`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is running in an azure function. And yes, the entire stack is using await.

Comment: What does `options` contain? It is not specified in the snippet. How are you passing the Partition Key to the Replace operation? It seems like you aren't.

Comment: I removed that line for conciseness. I'll add it back in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I do not quite understand the inner workings of the CosmosDb and related packages as it relates to this issue, it seems that the cause is a rewrite of how the Id field in a base class is written.

It used to be written this way:

```
public string id => Id;

public string Id { get; set; }
```

And then it got changed to:

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Note that the id => Id has been removed. And now it's causing issues. We changed it to:

```
public string id {
    get { return Id; }
    set { Id = value; }
}

public string Id { get; set; }
```

and now everything works like it used to.

Comment: This to me seems like a major change, it broke functionality in a pretty large way. The speed at which MS teams break backwards compatibility is appalling.

Comment: I had a similar issue by not having id at all and specifying an alternate Id as the main document id... this caused issues during Upserts... seems upsert only works with "id"

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the exact same error when trying to create a document. Although the ID of the document was unique, it slipped through my mind that I configured a unique key on the container.
As it is (almost?) impossible to find the unique keys defined on a container in Cosmos Db using the Azure portal, this can easily be overlooked.

Comment: This got me too. The error message is not helpful at all. The unique keys can be viewed by exporting the resource template: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490454/how-to-show-unique-keys-on-cosmos-db-container/59565064