# CosmosDB unique key issue

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, unique-key

I am facing issue with CosmosDB unique key constraint. After setting up the unique key, I am able to insert duplicate documents withing same partition key. Please help me to understand if I am doing anything wrong.

Created a container with the unique key as "/name" and partition key as "/partition"

I was able to create duplicate name under same partition key using azure portal data explorer tool

**Doc 1**

```
{
"id": "1",
"partition": "p1",
"name": "Balaji",
"age": 20,
"_rid": "Y48OAI3aptUBAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/Y48OAA==/colls/Y48OAI3aptU=/docs/Y48OAI3aptUBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"8e016bfd-0000-0700-0000-5e96d8a50000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1586944165
}
```

**Doc 2**

```
{
"id": "2",
"partition": "p1",
"name": "Balaji",
"age": 20,
"_rid": "Y48OAI3aptUCAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/Y48OAA==/colls/Y48OAI3aptU=/docs/Y48OAI3aptUCAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"8f017400-0000-0700-0000-5e96d8d60000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1586944214
}
```

Advance Thanks !!

Comment: I just tried this and I was not able to save the data (got the constraint violation error). Please check if you have set the unique key policy correctly.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri, apparently looks like the issue with Azure portal Data explorer UI issue. When creating a container from Azure portal, its not considering the provided unique key information.

Answer (score 5):

Drop the container and recreate it with unique key. You can't see unique key information in anywhere in UI
that makes debugging very difficult.
Also, check out my blog about unique key for more information if you like.
https://h-savran.blogspot.com/2019/08/how-unique-is-azure-cosmos-db-unique.html

Comment: In the portal you can see the unique key constraints by exporting the ARM template.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59565064/2914856

Comment: Man, as much as it is good getting traffic on your blog, it might go away whenever you/blogger or something else decides it.
It would be nice if you could get details about the unique keys here as a proper answer.